# Get and Set methods in another classes

Tags: java, class, methods, setter, getter

Im learning java and I have problem with get and set methods in other classes.

My first class is named Department and second is named Company. I would like to set number of staff in class Department and get number of staff in class Company.

Department class

```
public class Department {

    public int staffNumber;

    public Department() {
    }

    public void setStaffNumber(int staff) {
        this.staffNumber= staff;
    }

}
```

Company class

```
public class Company {

     public Department staffNumber;

     public Company() {
     }

     public Department getStaffNumber() {
          return Department.staffNumber = Department.staffNumber;
     }

}
```

Can you please help me with error message - non-static variable staffNumber cannot be referenced from a static context ? 
Thank you

Comment: public int getStaffNumber() {
          return Department.staffNumber = Department.staffNumber;
     }

Comment: There are a number of strange things in this code. Why is your member variable of type `Department` called `staffNumber`? Why does the method `getStaffNumber()` return a `Department` object? A "staff number" isn't the same as a department, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return Department.staffNumber = Department.staffNumber;
```

The compiler will read `Department.staffNumber` as: `staffNumber` is a static variable in the `Department` class. There your problem.

In order to solve this, you should just return the instance data:

```
public Department getStaffNumber() {
    //<Department attribute in the class>
    return staffNumber;
}
```

By the way,even if you have a `Department.staffNumber` static attribute inside the `Department` class, the proposed line `return Department.staffNumber = Department.staffNumber;` won't make any sense. It's similar to this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    int x;

    public int getX() {
        //return x = x; //clumsy
        return x; //now this might be better
    }
}
```

Comment: @Perroloco no, I didn't. I was just updating the answer step by step. Otherwise I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Perroloco Luiggi edited the question, he didn't ask it if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, because I'm beginner...But I've tried to replace `return Department.staffNumber = Department.staffNumber;` with `return staffNumber;` and I still dont get what I want. When I call method set and put some number and then call method get I get "null". I hope you understand, what I want to say.

Comment: @PerDeDor when you create an instance of a class, all the inner class variables (like `Department staffNumber`) will be initialized with the default value: `null`. If you haven't changed this behavior anywhere in your program, then it will always return `null`. You can change the behavior by: 1. Creating the instance of the `staffNumber` attribute in the `Company` constructor, 2. Creating a `public void setStaffNumber(Department staffNumber) { this.staffNumber = staffNumber; }` method in your `Company` class and calling it to set a new instance of the `staffNumber` attribute.

Comment: @PerDeDor also, try to make your attributes `private` or `protected`, not public, because it break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public Department getStaffNumber() {
          return Department.staffNumber = Department.staffNumber;
     }
```

Department.staffNumber is accessed like a static variable. 
It should be `return staffNumber`.

Your getter normally wouldn't init. It should just *return*.

If you want to return Department then it should be `return staffNumber`

If you want to return Department.staffNumber it should be 
return `staffNumber.staffNumber` changing the return type to an `int`... and fix the variable names!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to acces the variable staffNumber as it was a [static variable](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/staticvariable.shtml).

If you want to return the staffNumber, you should return staffNumber.staffNumber. You are using bad semantics though...you should have:

```
public class Company {

     public Department m_department;

     public Company() {
         m_department=new Department();
     }

     public Department getStaffNumber() {
          return m_department.staffNumber;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about basic concepts.
Do the following

```
public class Department {

    public int staffNumber;

    public Department() {
    }

    public void setStaffNumber(int staff) {
        this.staffNumber= staff;
    }

    public int getStaffNumber() {
        return staffNumber;
    }
}
```

Now using `StaffNumber` in your `Company` class

```
public class Company {

    public Department dept;

    public Company() {
        dept= new Department();
    }

    public int getDepartmentStaffNumber() {
        return dept.getStaffNumber();
    }

    public void setDepartmentStaffNumber(int staff) {
        dept.setStaffNumber(staff)
    }
}
```